# $\frac{dS}{d\rho}$ Factor arising

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

To get details see: [equations 29,30,31,34,44,50,51](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)

We have known some solitary wave solutions, given by(equations 1 to 5) 
$$
\phi_1=p_1\cos \tau \tag{1}$$
$$\phi_2=\frac16 g_2p_1^2\left(\cos(2\tau)-3\right)\tag{2}$$
$$\phi_3=p_3\cos \tau+\frac{1}{72}(4g_2^2-3\lambda)p_1^3\cos(3\tau)\tag{3}$$
$$\phi_4=
\frac{1}{360}p_1^4\left(3g_4-5g_2\lambda+5g_2^3\right)\cos(4\tau)
-\frac{1}{72}\left(8g_2(\nabla p_1)^2-12g_4p_1^4+16g_2^3p_1^4
-24g_2p_1p_3-23g_2\lambda p_1^4-8g_2p_1^2\right)\cos(2\tau)
-g_2p_1^2-g_2p_1p_3+\frac{1}{6}g_2\lambda p_1^4-g_2(\nabla p_1)^2
+\frac{31}{72}g_2^3p_1^4-\frac{3}{8}g_4p_1^4 
\tag{4}$$
\begin{equation}
p_5=\frac{\sqrt 2}{9\sqrt 3}\left(
Y-\frac{1235}{32}S^2Z+\frac{1503}{16}Z-24S-\frac{17}{3}S^3
+\frac{11525}{384}S^5\right) 
\end{equation}
Now we will set $\tau=0$ in these above equation.
Now consider some conditions:

1. $$S=p_1\sqrt{\lambda}$$
2. \begin{equation}
   p_3=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}\left(
   \frac{65}{8}Z-\frac{8}{3}S-\frac{19}{12}S^3
   \right)\,.
   \end{equation}
   3.value of the  some constants $g_2=-\frac32$, $g_3=\frac12$ and $g_i=0$ for $i\geq 4$ ,$ \lambda= \frac{3}{2}$

and equations of spherical symmetry

1. \begin{equation}
   \frac{d^2S}{d\rho^2}+\frac{D-1}{\rho}\,\frac{dS}{d\rho}
   -S+S^3=0
   \end{equation}

Now I need write the equations (4)and (5) as 
$$\phi_4^{(\tau=0)}=\frac{1}{9}\left[
\frac{65}{4}SZ+10\left(\frac{dS}{d\rho}\right)^2
+\frac{8}{3}S^2-\frac{125}{12}S^4
\right]$$
$$\phi_5^{(\tau=0)}=\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\Biggl[
Y-\frac{2275}{64}S^2Z+\frac{1503}{16}Z
-\frac{15}{32}S\left(\frac{dS}{d\rho}\right)^2
-24S-\frac{595}{96}S^3+\frac{11285}{384}S^5
\biggr]$$
**My Problem is how the factor $\frac{dS}{d\rho}$ arises in  the above two equations?**
For further details: [equations 29,30,31,34,44,50,51](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)
If you have problem to understand the questions then ask me please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: $S = p_1 \sqrt{\lambda}$, assuming $\lambda$ is a constant we have $\nabla p_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \nabla S$. Since $S$ is spherically symmetric $\nabla S = (\partial_\rho S) \partial_\rho$ where $\rho$ is the radial coordinate.

Comment: *The question is widely applicable to a large audience*... It would help if you explained why you think so.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the gradient $\nabla S$ is just $\partial S/\partial \rho$ (due to spherical symmetry), and $S$ is just a constant times $p_1$. Since everything else except $p_3$ is a constant, you can just plug this all in and get the answer.

For the fifth equation $\phi_5$, take equation 34 and plug in 47, and use the spherical gradient as in the previous case.

After multiplying out equation 34 and substituting $\tau=0$, the only term with the gradient is $\frac{12S(\nabla S)^2}{384\sqrt{\lambda}}$. But using the spherical gradient and formula for $\lambda$, this is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{3S(\partial S/\partial \rho)^2}{96}$. But in the last equation of your post, the term with the derivative simplifies to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{5S(\partial S/\partial \rho)^2}{96}$. Because they are so close, there is probably just a typo; equation 34 should probably say 15.

Take their equation 34 and set $\tau=0$ and you will get $p_5+\frac{S^5}{1152\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}(\frac{4g_5}{3}+2)-\frac{S}{384\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}[(\frac{40g_5}{3}+2)SZ+12S^2-12(\partial S/\partial \rho)^2-(\frac{20g_5}{3}-2)S^4]$. Plugging in for $p_5$, we get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9\sqrt{3}}(Y-\frac{1235}{32}S^2Z+\frac{1503}{16}Z-24S-\frac{17}{3}S^3+\frac{1125}{384}S^5)+\frac{S^5}{1152\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}(\frac{4g_5}{3}+2)-\frac{S}{384\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}[(\frac{40g_5}{3}+2)SZ+12S^2-12(\partial S/\partial \rho)^2-(\frac{20g_5}{3}-2)S^4]$.

Collecting like terms, we get

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates using the fact it's spherically symmetric.

Comment: Can you do it for $\phi_5$  please?

Comment: I think you wrote down $p_5$ on accident instead of $\phi_5$. What is the equation for $\phi_5$?

Comment: Never mind, I found it.

Comment: Yes, and equation 34 is the one to use to evaluate it.

Comment: Yup you right, but I filed to get  $\partial S/\partial \rho$ in right way. :-(

Comment: Don't forget it is all multiplied by S/384. Doing it my way gives you 5/96 as a coefficient, but they have 3/96, so they may have a typo, because there is no other factor that has $\nabla$ in it.

Comment: Can you write your works please, then I can understand more.

Comment: The author of the stated that, The equations from (46) are valid for the double well potential, for which $g_2=-3/2$,$ g_3=1/2$, other $g_i$ are zero. Now g_2 is not zero, so we cannot use (33) and (34) in this case.We get (34) from the epsilon^5 component of (9), assuming that all $g_{2i}=0$. 
 Is this helpful?

Comment: That makes sense; looking through, they never state the full equations. I believe that they simply derived them outside of the paper and wrote them down. But you can get a lot of the terms correctly from 34 and 47, so I would use that as a guide. But I get the feeling that they derived the equations through a great deal of effort and just wrote it down without showing the difficult derivation.

Comment: Absolute  right you are. I'm trying also. :-(

Comment: Thanks for your attempting, but please write the process they did,  if you can get the equation.

Comment: But this is not resembling with the article equation!!!

Comment: @ Brian Rushton, What i can guess is, we can not use the article equation (47) to evaluate the equation (52) but we need to find out the value of $\phi_5$ from the equation (34) for considering $g_2 = g_4 =0$ . I feel problem to get the value of $p_5$

Comment: I'm gonna opening a botuny for the post, can you check the question?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413748/finding-the-value-of-p-5