# Radial coordinate evaluation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Details of the question can be found in the [article equation(55,56)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)

A radial coordinate $R$ defined by
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{2R}{\kappa(1-R^2)} \,,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$ is a constantand the range is
$0\leq r<\infty$ and radial coordinate $r$ is mapped to
the interval $0\leq R<1$, calculations we
used $\kappa=5\varepsilon$.

We consider a scalar theory in a $1+D$ dimensional flat Minkowski
space-time, with a general self-interaction
potential, whose action can be written as
\begin{equation}
A=\int dt\, d^D\! x \left[\frac12(\partial_t\phi)^2-\frac12(\partial_i\phi)^2
-U(\phi)\right] \,,
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is a real scalar field, $\partial_t=\partial/\partial t$,
$\partial_i=\partial/\partial x^i$ and $i=1,2,\ldots,D$.
The equation of motion following from
is a non-linear wave equation (NLWE) which is given as
\begin{equation}
 -\phi_{,tt} + \Delta \phi = U'(\phi)=\phi +\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}g_k\phi^k\,,\quad
{\rm where}\quad{\Delta}=\sum_{i=1}^{D}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}\,.
\tag{1} \end{equation}
Using the radial coordinate $R$ the above field equation (1) takes the
form
\begin{equation}
\phi_{,tt}=
\frac{\kappa^2(1-R^2)^3}{2(1+R^2)}\left[
\frac{(1-R^2)}{2(1+R^2)}
\phi_{,RR}
-\frac{R(3+R^2)}{(1+R^2)^2}
\phi_{,R}
+\frac{(D-1)}{2R}
\phi_{,R}
\right]
-U'(\phi) \,.\tag{2}
\end{equation}

> My problem is to get the idea that how equation (2) arises from (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're using the spherical form of the Laplacian and assuming that $\phi$ depends only on $r$. ThEn they are using the chain rule: $\phi_{r}=\phi_{R}R_r=\phi_R \frac{\kappa (1-R^2)^2}{2(1+R^2)}$, since $R_r=1/r_R$.

Then $\phi{rr}=(\phi_R \frac{\kappa (1-R^2)^2}{2(1+R^2)})_R R_r$ by the same reasoning, which is $(\phi_{RR}\frac{\kappa (1-R^2)^2}{2(1+R^2)}-\phi_{R}\frac{\kappa R(3+R^2)(1-R^2)}{(1+R^2)^2})\frac{\kappa (1-R^2)^2}{2(1+R^2)}$.

The third term in equation two comes directly from the corresponding term in the spherical Laplacian, but hey pull some stuff out of it; in fact, they pull $(1-R^2)R_r \kappa$ out of everything. And that's where it comes from.

Comment: Hey thanks, can you check my another unsolved questions:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/fracdsd-rho-factor
and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407665/solving-the-time-average-over-energy