# Searching for the value of $p_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, solution-verification

Reference [post: click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/fracdsd-rho-factor)

Given,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\Delta p_5-p_5+3S^2p_5
+\frac{SZ}{576\sqrt{\lambda}}(3Z-5S^3)
\left(\frac{15g_5}{\lambda^2}+1\right)^2\nonumber\\
&&+\frac{S^3}{32\sqrt{\lambda}}\left[(\nabla S)^2-S^2\right]
-\frac{S^7}{576\sqrt{\lambda}}\left(\frac{315g_7}{\lambda^3}
-\frac{60g_5}{\lambda^2}+1\right)=0 \,.
\end{eqnarray}
Where, $\Delta$ is double derivative.

I need to evaluate the solution for $p_5$, so the equation 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\phi_5=p_5
+\frac{S^5}{1152\sqrt{\lambda}}\left(\frac{3g_5}{\lambda^2}+2\right)
\nonumber\\
&&-\frac{S}{384\sqrt{\lambda}}\left[
\left(\frac{30g_5}{\lambda^2}+2\right)SZ+12S^2-12(\nabla S)^2
-\left(\frac{15g_5}{\lambda^2}-2\right)S^4
\right] \,.
\end{eqnarray}
will take this form,

$$\phi_5=\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\Biggl[
Y-\frac{2275}{64}S^2Z+\frac{1503}{16}Z
-\frac{15}{32}S\left(\frac{dS}{d\rho}\right)^2
-24S-\frac{595}{96}S^3+\frac{11285}{384}S^5
\biggr]$$
Where $g_3= -\frac{3}{2}, g_5= 0, \lambda= \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Homework questions? What have you tried?

Comment: What are $S,Z,Y$?

Comment: These are clearly stated in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/fracdsd-rho-factor-arising
$$S=p_1\sqrt{\lambda}$$
\begin{equation}
p_3=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}\left(
\frac{65}{8}Z-\frac{8}{3}S-\frac{19}{12}S^3
\right)\,.
\end{equation}

Comment: @ComplexGuy You should either link or restate here. =)

Answer (score 0):

In the paper, they don't actually solve the equation for $p_5$, or for $p_1$ or $p_3$, for that matter. In each case they introduce a new variable that allows them to manipulate equations. So, for instance, $S$ is defined by the equation $S=p_1 \sqrt{\lambda}$. We have not actually solved $p_1$, we're just defining $S$. Similarly, $Z$ is **defined** by the equation $p_3=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}}(\frac{65}{8}Z-\frac{8}{3}S-\frac{19}{12}S^3)$.

Similarly, $p_5$ is not actually solved; instead, equation 47 is used to define a new variable $Y$ that has never appeared before. So the form they give for $\phi_5$ is obtained simply by plugging in equation 47.

Comment: Yup right you are, how how will we do these smart guess? 
By comparing  two equations, can we evaluate the value of $p_5$?

Comment: I need the solution for $p_5$ to get the article equation (52). http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525